# Passing multiple arguments in return 'Response' (python)

Tags: python, angular, httprequest, httpresponse

I am working in Angular and I am using Http Request and Response.
Is it possible to send multiple arguments in 'Response'.

Angular file:

```
this.http.get("api/agent/applicationaware").subscribe((data:any)...
```

python file:

```
def get(request):
    ...
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

I want to send multiple arguments in the Response.
Like

```
return Response(serializer.data,obj.someothervalue)
```

can you help me with this?
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can return a `dictionary`

```
return Response({'serializer_data': serializer.data, 'some_other_value': obj.someothervalue})
```

Or you can append `someothervalue` to `serializer.data`

```
data = serializer.data
data['someothervalue'] = obj.someothervalue
return Response(data)
```

If `obj.someothervalue` is a dictionary as well, then you can merge two dictionaries:

```
data = serializer.data.copy()
data.update(obj.someothervalue)
return Response(data)
```

Comment: Thank you Harun for your response

Answer (score 1):

add a dictionary

```
dict = {}
dict['details'] = serializer.data
dict['other'] = someotherdata
return Response(dict)
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You need to decide a protocol for API response first and then you can plan accordingly.

To answer your question, YES you can send multiple args in response.

You can create a dictionary/list and put all the values you want to send inside it. Now send that dictionary/list as your response.
I would recommend something kind of this :

```
response = dict()
response["data"] = dict()
response["data"]["serializer_data"] = serializer.data
response["data"]["some_other_value"] = obj.someothervalue

return Response(response)
```

On the receiving end of the response you will have to read the response data in similar way you sent it.